# Parallelizing repeated calls to member function

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am trying to parallelize the call to a member function using `joblib`:

```
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

class C(object):

    def func_change(self, i):
        self.arr[i]=2*i           

    def __init__(self):            
        self.arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    C_object = C()
    print(C_object.arr)
    Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(C_object.func_change)(i) for i in range(2))
    print(C_object.arr)
```

This outputs

```
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3]
```

so it doesn't seem to work. Is a different approach/design required of my class in order to achieve this?

Comment: Multiprocessing does not share state

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Do I have any alternatives here or do I have to re-design the class? Or maybe move the parallelization into the member function?

Comment: You need to not rely on shared state, or use one of the options for doing so. Read the multiprocessing docs.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is it possible to do the above while not relying on shared state?

Comment: Did you read the docs? It is non-trivial.